# Flash Player looks for crossdomain in site root URL and hangs

Tags: flash, crossdomain.xml, cross-domain-policy

I have flash on my `site.com` and resources (images) on other site with IP address only (suppose `1.1.1.1`).

I have itemrenderers with `s:Image sorce="{FullPathTo1.1.1.1/imageName}"`.

In `http://1.1.1.1/crossdomain.xml` we have:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="site.com"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*.site.com"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

When FlashPlayer loads images to itemrenderers - it for unknown reason requests not only for `http://1.1.1.1/crossdomain.xml`, but for `http://1.1.1.1/` (root site).  There is no default answer in 1.1.1.1 root - it is totally empty page. But, after that flash throws uncaught ioError (not s:Images, but some system class).

What i tried to fix:

1. If i hide `s:Image` in item renderer - now error. So, exactly this
   images loading generates error.
2. If i substitute `http://1.1.1.1/` root answer to `http://1.1.1.1/crossdomain.xml` in a proxy - flash player works correct without any error.

So, for some stupid reason it looks for `crossdomain.xml` in the root URL, but not `http://1.1.1.1/crossdomain.xml`

Does anybody know the reason and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue:
I used `Image.contentLoader = ContentCache`

And this stupid ContentCache bugs on crossdomain policies. So i used other cachin mechanism, which i used in same project for loaded SFW's.